# How to limit pyspark ressources

Tags: pyspark

I'm running `pyspark` in my local machine, and I want to limit the number of used cores and used memory (I've 8 cores and 16Gb of memory)

I don't know how to do this, I've tried to add these lines to my code, but the process is still greedy.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]")
    .set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
    .set("spark.cores.max", "4")
    .set('spark.executor.memory', '6g')
)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
rdd = sc.parallelize(input_data, numSlices=4)

map_result = rdd.map(map_func)
map_result.reduce(reduce_func)
```

Why do the confs are not applied ?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happennig due to "precedence" in configurations. Since Spark allows different ways to set configuration parameters. In the documentation we can see:

> Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application and merged with those specified through SparkConf. Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.

For more info: [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties)

So I suggest reviewing spark-submit parameters and configuration files.

Hope it helps.